# How can I extract the page title by using REGEXP_EXTRACT function?

Tags: looker-studio

My website's Page Title is like below format:

aaaa | bbbb | cccc | dddd

I would like to extract bbbb only

but when I used the below REGEXP_EXTRACT:

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(page title, '\\|(.*)\\|')` , which only return the result of bbbb | cccc.

I would like to know how to rewrite the formula to extract bbbb only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page Title,"^(?:[^\\|]*\\|){1}([^\\|]*)"))
```

- you can also change the number within curly braces to pick the value after certain `|`; if you give it `2` it results in `cccc` and `3` gives `dddd`

[image]